# Undo last operation in aptitude

Tags: apt, aptitude

While I was resolving some dependencies in aptitude, I miss-clicked and chose an option I didn't want. Quite a few packages were installed and even more were removed.

I can see what happened in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. However, I am unsure how to best revert (undo) this last operation.

Is there any automated or recommended way to (un)do this?

Complementary questions:

- If a package is listed under the keyword `Install`, does it necessarily mean that it was not previously installed in any version (so I can safely remove it)? Or can it mean that it was upgraded to the listed version?
- Is there a simple way to show the list of packages from `history.log` without the versions? Or a way of passing the list (with versions) directly to `apt`/`apt-get`/`aptitude`?